# Error in database connection or query

Tags: java, database, connection

I tried to connect to a database, but java error handling keep giving me this error"Error in database connection or query"

My code is like this

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);      
System.out.println("Connection established: My data.");

Statement st = connection.createStatement();            
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
```

And the strQuery is a string

```
String strQuery="SELECT * FROM database.MINIMUM_TIMES";
```

The concole window can print out "Connection established: My data.";
but then give me "Error in database connection or query"

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you try query without database name?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: It would help if you posted the entire exception message and stack trace.

Comment: I simplified the strQuery because it's too long. But even though I just use the simple query like i listed above, it doesn't work. The stack trace looks just like this

Comment: Connection established: MCT data.
Error in database connection or query.

Comment: It doesn't give me any detail information

Comment: @user1652926: Which Database are you using?

Comment: @Vishal K, I'm using a database which is provided by an organization. I can get access to the data in SQL Developer, but I cannot use my query in java. I think the problem is in java. But seems like I can get connection to the database using java because I have the"Connection established"sentence

Comment: @user1652926: Have you tried following query: `SELECT * FROM MINIMUM_TIMES` ?

Comment: @Vishal K: Yes, I also tried that

Comment: I Guess `database` is a schema in the Database that you are using. You check your URL that you are passing in `getConnection` method..And put the schema as `database`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

> String strQuery="SELECT * FROM MINIMUM_TIMES";

Assuming MINIMUM_TIMES is your table in the db which you already established a connection.